# Do tensor cores provide advantages for running Stable Diffusion or only for training?

Tags: gpu, hardware, diffusion-models

If I am only interested in running Stable Diffusion, using pre-trained weights, to generate images, are there any advantages to using a GPU with more Tensor cores?  Or will any CUDA-compatible GPU perform equivalently on this task?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference that describes this "stable diffusion"? Are you referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_Diffusion)?

Comment: Yes exactly, specifically this implementation: https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion